# Mocking a module imported in a vue component with Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, jestjs

I'm having some issues processing the [documentation of Jest](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks#automatic-mock), because I expected this code to work:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from '@/router/index';
import OrdersService from '@/services/orders.service';

jest.mock('@/services/orders.service');

describe('OrdersItem.vue', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    // mockClear does not exist
    OrdersService.mockClear();
  });

  it('should render expected list contents', () => {
    // Orders.mock is undefined 
    OrdersService.getAll.mockResolvedValue([ ... ]);
    // ...
```

However it does not. It fails as-if `OrdersService` was never mocked. I've also tried stuff like:

```
jest.mock('@/services/orders.service', () => jest.fn());
jest.mock('@/services/orders.service', () => { getAll: jest.fn() });
```

First one replaces the whole service with a mock function (I'd like to achieve that automatic mocking functionality mentioned in the docs, where all the methods from the original are auto-replaced with mock fn).
Second one fails same way as the `.mock` call with just the module path.

What am I doing wrong here and why?

`orders.service` skeleton:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import config from '../config/config.json';
import Order from '../models/order';

class OrdersService {
  constructor(httpClient) {
    this.httpClient = httpClient;
  }

  getAll() {
      // ...
  }
}
export default new OrdersService(axios);
```

Comment: Could you show the skeleton of the `order.service`?

Comment: I guess the problem here is that you are returning an instance, and not a class in itself

Comment: @Icepickle could you explain?

Answer (score 5):

It looks like there is an issue in with `jest.mock` ([#4262](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/4262)) concerning `moduleNameMapper` for module resolvers, aliases, path, whatever you want to call using `@/something`.

```js
// you cannot use a module resolver (i.e. '@')
jest.mock('@/services/orders.service');

// you must use the full path to the file for the import and mock
import OrdersService from '../../src/services/orders.service';
jest.mock('../../src/services/orders.service');
```

Stay tuned to updates on the issue, looks like the last update was on [9/28](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/4262#issuecomment-425378049).

Secondly, provided you fix the issue above, you are exporting a class instance not the class itself, as is done in the Jest example. Therefore, you will not have access to the `clearMock` method on the `OrdersService` but rather you can call `clearMock` on each mocked method on the class instance.

```js
// mockClear will be undefined
OrdersService.mockClear();

// mockClear is defined
OrdersService.getAll.mockClear();
```

If you want to export the instance as you are, you could just clear all mocks using [`jest.clearAllMocks`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestclearallmocks) in the `beforeEach` or loop through all methods and call `mockClear` on each. Otherwise exporting the class itself will give you access to `OrdersService.mockClear` which will ...

> Clear all instances and calls to constructor and all methods [(ref)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks#automatic-mock)

This seems to be useful in cases where the mocked class is being used/instantiated in another class that you are trying to test, as in the jest example.

*All of this has been tested and confirmed using Jest v23.6 and vue-cli v3.0.4.*

Comment: Thanks mate, I appreciate the research. However it seems like in my particular case switching import statements to use relative paths didn't solve it for me. 
In the end I used manual mocks, creating `__mocks__` dirs next to mocked modules and abandoning es6 classes in favor of exporting object literals with methods. I don't find it very elegant, but it seems to work so far. Now I got other problems, so it's likely that my orignal problem will also be solved with some updates to jest (22.0.4), vue-test-utils (1.0.0-beta.25, sic), babel-jest (21.0.2) etc.

Comment: No worries, sorry that didn't work in your case. Ya I typically just mock out what I need and ignore the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Since the OrdersService is an instance of the class, it will return an object and you would need to mock all the properties exposed by this object manually.

You could try with the following implementation to mock your function. [Reference docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object.html#jestfnimplementation)

```
OrdersService.getAll = jest.fn(()=>{
// mock implementation here;
});
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try calling `jest.resetModules()` in the `beforeEach` block, that might cause the mocked service to be used

Answer (score 0):

Try to import everything with an alias and set the mock on the alias.

```
import * as OrdersModule from '@/services/orders.service';
OrdersModule.getAll = jest.fn()
```

I found it in the bible:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules

Answer (score 0):

Running into this and had some issues with trying to get "mount" to work without having to manually set a bunch of things and the easiest way to get this work was importing the module:

```
import TestThisModule from 'testThisModule';
```

and then directly writing a `spyon` for the methods I watched to write tests for by accessing the module's prototype:

```
const resetMethodSpy = jest.spyOn(TestThisModule.prototype, 'reset');
const { wrapper } = factory();
await (wrapper.vm as any).triggerMethod();
expect(resetMethodSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```