# Jest: Vue Component can't find mocked function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs

I'm mocking a ES6 class which is used inside my Vue Component:

```
export default class DataUploadApi {
    // Get uploaded files
    static async getUploadedFiles() : Promise<Object> {
        return WebapiBase.getAsync({uri: DATA_UPLOAD_ENPOINTS.FILES});
    }
}
```

I've been following along with [this](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks) document, but I think my syntax is slightly off with my mock:

```
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import DataUploadApi from '../webapi/DataUploadService';
import FileDownloadList from '../components/file-download-list.vue';

const mockGetUploadedFiles = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({json: JSON.stringify(uploadedFilesObj)});
jest.mock('../webapi/DataUploadService', () => jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({getUploadedFiles: mockGetUploadedFiles})));

describe('file-download-list component', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        // @ts-ignore
        DataUploadApi.mockClear(); // https://stackoverflow.com/a/52707663/1695437 dont use @ imports on mocks.
        mockGetUploadedFiles.mockClear();
    });
    describe('renders correct markup:', () => {
        it('without any uploaded files', () => {
            const wrapper = mount(FileDownloadList, {});
            expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
        });
    });
});
```

This test passes. However, in the snapshot I can see that the API called failed with this error message:

```
<p>
    _DataUploadService.default.getUploadedFiles is not a function
</p>
```

What have I done wrong with the function mock? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seemed to be a few issues with my code:

### Mocking the API

Using an internal `mockImplementation` seems to cause issues, and is not required if you don't need the additional mock functionality.

```
jest.mock('@/apps/gb-data/webapi/DataUploadService', () => ({
    getUploadedFiles() {
        return Promise.resolve({ uploaded_files: {} });
    },
}));
```

### Changes to the test

Both [`flushPromises`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flush-promises) and `nextTick` are required.

```
 it('with uploaded files', async () => {
     const wrapper = mount(FileDownloadList, {
         stubs: fileDownloadListStubs,
     });
     await flushPromises();
     await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();
     expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```